# Differential Equations: Represent the following family of curve by a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Represent the following family of curves by forming a corresponding differential equations:
>   
> $$(vi) \frac {x^2}{a^2}-\frac {y^2}{b^2}=1$$

a and b are the parameters here.

I differentiated y, solved a and b, substituted them to get an answer which was long and wrong.

Please offer your assistance
Thank you

Comment: Did you take express y in terms of x and differentiated or did you directly differentiate the expression w.r.t x? Please show us the calculation steps. Most likely that you have made a calculation error.

Comment: $$\frac{2x}{a^2}-\frac{2y}{b^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ or $$2b^2x-2a^2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2x}{a^2}-\frac{2y}{b^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=0 $$
Multiplying both sides by $a^2b^2$ we get,
$$xb^2-a^2yy\prime=0$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t x
$$b^2-a^2((y\prime)^2+yy\prime\prime)=0$$
$$\frac {b^2}{a^2}=(y\prime)^2+yy\prime\prime$$
Multiply both sides of the first equation by $b^2$ and substitue the value of $\frac {b^2}{a^2}$ from the last equation to get the required differential equation.

Comment: Got it. thanks. Missed the $b^2/a^2$ part

Answer (score 1):

You must differentiate twice to get rid of $a$ and $b.$
Differentiate the given equation with respect to $x$ to get
$$\frac{2x}{a^2} -\frac{2y\, \mathrm{d} y}{b^2 \mathrm{d} x}= 0$$
$$\frac{x}{a^2} -\frac{y}{b^2} \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{ \mathrm{d} x}= 0$$
$$\frac{y\, \mathrm{d} y}{x\, \mathrm{d} x}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$
$$\frac{yy'}{x}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$

Differentiate both side with respect to $x$ again:
$$\frac{x[{(y')^2}+yy'']-yy'}{x^2}=0$$

Thus, the differential equation is finally:
$$x(y')^2+xyy''-yy'=0.$$

Comment: Upvoted. Liked this better. But first answer got the tick.